# Hibernate:id value is being saved as null

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am saving Employee object into Sql Server 2012 but the ID value is always [!   [saved as null][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uRoy.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uRoy.jpg), 
I have used strategy Identity,Auto,Sequence

Employee Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Employee")
public class Student {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
int id;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
String name;
String email;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
```

DAO Class is:-

```
public class SaveDao {

SessionFactory factory = factorypattern.getfactory();
Session session = factory.openSession();
Transaction tx =session.beginTransaction();


// saving using save method with transaction so OK case
public void saveStudent() {

    System.out.println("******save method*****");

    try {
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setEmail("raja@gmail");
        student.setName("raja");
        session.save(student);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        tx.rollback();
    }
}
```

whenever i am using

```
 SaveDao save=new SaveDao();

 save.saveStudent();
```

id null is inserted in DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do following:

1) Make sure you database generates ids on insert:

```
ALTER TABLE [yourTable] DROP COLUMN ID 
ALTER TABLE [yourTable] ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

2) Use IDENTITY strategy

3) Not problem related thought, but transaction should be started in the method, not on class level of DAO object